# Collecting multivariate polynomials

Tags: symbolic, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

In a way of minimal example, say I want to collect the expansion of $(a+b+x+y)^2$ with respect to $x$ and $y$.  `Collect[(a+b+x+y)^2,{x,y}]` gives nested collection (sums involving $y$ as coefficients at powers of $x$) which is not what I want. Most concise code that I could find for it is

```
Total[Map[Last[#]Times@@({x,y}^First[#])&,CoefficientRules[(a+b+x+y)^2,{x,y}]]]
```

(which correctly gives `a^2 + 2 a b + b^2 + (2 a + 2 b) x + x^2 + (2 a + 2 b) y + 2 x y + y^2`).

Is there more straightforward way to do it?

Comment: @MarcoB This results in `a^2 + 2ab + b^2 + x^2 + (2a + 2b)y + y^2 + x(2a + 2b + 2y)` which is not what I want.

Comment: Oh I see. I was careless in reading the desired format.

Comment: @MarcoB I added explanation about that

Comment: Something like this? `In[1514]:= Plus @@ MonomialList[Expand[(a + b + x + y)^2], {x, y}]

Out[1514]= a^2 + 2 a b + b^2 + (2 a + 2 b) x + x^2 + (2 a + 2 b) y + 
 2 x y + y^2`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I think this is optimal - at any rate better than my version. Could you please make this an answer? I was not aware of `MonomialList`. It is very nice also because you can reorder the summands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can use `MonomialList` to separate power products involving a specified set of variables. In this example it might be done as below.

```
Plus @@ MonomialList[Expand[(a + b + x + y)^2], {x, y}]

(* Out[1549]= a^2 + 2 a b + b^2 + (2 a + 2 b) x + x^2 + (2 a + 2 b) y + 
 2 x y + y^2 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
lst = Rest @ Flatten @ Array[x^# y^#2 &, {3, 3}, 0]


(* {y, y^2, x, x y, x y^2, x^2, x^2 y, x^2 y^2} *)
```

and then

```
 Collect[Expand[(a + b + x + y)^2], lst]

(*  a^2 + 2 a b + b^2 + (2 a + 2 b) x + x^2 + (2 a + 2 b) y + 2 x y + y^2  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Alexei, your `Collect` expression does nothing to the expanded multinomial. Indeed, your final output is the same as `Expand[(a + b + x + y)^2]`. Notice also that it is not what the OP wanted as output.

Comment: @MarcoB The OP writes: "gives nested collection (sums involving y as coefficients at powers of x) which is not what I want". That's how I interpreted his words. If it is not the case he should be more precise.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. In your version, why are the terms, say, `2ay+2by` not collected together like `(2a+2b)y`??

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე  Sorry, it is because I skipped omitting 1 in the first step. I fixed this. Please have a look at the edits.

Comment: Oh I see, good, thanks. I could accept this one too, I only stay with the previous one since I like `MonomialList` :)